# Iframe hover opacity change not working in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, iframe, opacity, microsoft-edge

I have a simple class defined in css for an iframe that holds a slideshow pulled from Smugmug.  The basic function is a 25% opacity when the user does not hover over the slideshow and a transition to 100% opacity when the user hovers over the iframe area.  This works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not in Microsoft Edge.  In Edge, I get the 25% opacity and transitions, but the hover does not lift the opacity.

Does anyone know why Edge does not work?  Am I missing some directive for the Edge browser?

Here is an example of the iframe . . .

```
<div id=avalon class="slide">
  <iframe src="https://johndoc1.smugmug.com/frame/slideshow?   key=M9jkGB&autoStart=1&captions=1&navigation=1&playButton=1&randomize=0&speed=4&transition=fade&transitionSpeed=2" width="1100" height="825" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is the css for the slide class . . .

```
/* Slideshow style */

.slide {
width:80%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background: #2F4538;
   }

.slide iframe{
opacity:0.25;
transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}

.slide iframe:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

Thanks.
John Doc

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is actually not very clean, but I tried several things and I was not able to make it run just via css. Maybe Edge is missing some directive in render core ... who knows.

Anyway... I was able to run it via javascript, in this solution I use jQuery as it is closer to me, I will add pure JS solutions as soon as I find, why jsfiddle cannot see my declared functions...

So - here it is:
https://jsfiddle.net/f4y0uugc/2/

note that jQuery code has to be on document ready.

theese are the major changes:

```
  $(".slide iframe").on("mouseover", function(){

$(this).addClass("slideiframe");
});

$(".slide iframe").on("mouseout", function(){
$(this).removeClass("slideiframe");
});
```

and css added just

```
    .slideiframe{
    opacity:1.0 !important;
}
```

//EDIT - pure JS

Ok, here is a pure solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/f4y0uugc/4/

here you have your JS:

```
var slide;

function op025(){
slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide")[0].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
slide.style.opacity = 0.5;
}

function op1(){
slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide")[0].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
slide.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Note, that classes and elements are arrays, yo if you have more than one matches, you will have to add IDs, or iterate in cycle for each solution.

Next, you have to set up calls of functions, so in html:

```
<div id=avalon class="slide">
  <iframe onmouseover="op1();" onmouseout="op025();" src="https://johndoc1.smugmug.com/frame/slideshow?   key=M9jkGB&autoStart=1&captions=1&navigation=1&playButton=1&randomize=0&speed=4&transition=fade&transitionSpeed=2" width="1100" height="825" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Also, for both solutions, as this is scripted soltion, I have reduced transition duration to 0.2s as if user quickly moves cursor over the edge, opacity behavior is not clean.

I will try something pure css more, and I will let you know if I find something.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Gotta brush up on my javascript.  If you come across a pure CSS solution, please pass it along.

Thanks again,
John